How do I pass data from a client component to a server action in Next.JS with the App Router?
I am using the Next.JS App router system, with the React useFormState hook as follows:
"use client"
// imports...

export default function EditCompanyDetailsForm({ company }: { company: Company }) {
    const [errorMessage, formAction] = useFormState(updateCompany, undefined);
    // return form with inputs etc for rendering

... and:
"use server"
...

export async function updateCompany(
    prevState: any,
    formData: FormData
) {
    const schema = z.object({
        name: z.string().trim().max(100).min(5),
        description: z.string().trim().max(1000).min(50),
        logoUrl: z.string().trim().max(1000).optional(),
        id: z.number().int()
    });

    try {
        const data = schema.parse({
            name: formData.get('name'),
            description: formData.get('description'),
            logoUrl: formData.get('logoUrl'),
            id: Number(formData.get('id'))
        });
        ... logic
...
}

My problem is that I need a secure way to pass the company ID from the company object in EditCompanyDetailsForm, to the updateCompany action, to tell it what company I am editing, so when the data is passed to a separate service (called via fetch), it can be used to update the database.
How do I do so? I know a hidden input would work but this can be edited by the client using inspect element from my tests, which I want to prevent (of course I will have to validate against this for security anyway). Preferably without using local API routes. Is there a better way to do this? Hidden input, it works but I can modify it from the HTML.
